# Multiple DropDown Menu list issue

Tags: jquery, html

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style=background-color:lightgreen;">
<!--font size="30" color="red">
<font size="10"-->

</p> <font size="30"> <font color="black"> <center> MSOC Tools and Database </font></p>


</p> <font size="10"> <font color="red"> <left> On-Boarding Documents </font></p>


<form name="jump">
<p align="left-side" >
<select name="menu">
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/Orchard%20Hotel%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">Orchard Hotel</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/Orchard%20Hotel%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">IDA</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/Park%20Regis%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">Park Regis</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/Golden%20Village%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">Golden Village</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/Orchard%20Hotel%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">NTUC Link</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/MediaCorp%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">MediaCorp</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/South%20Beach%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">South Beach</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/Golden%20Village%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">Golden Village</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/Orchard%20Hotel%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">Gallery</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/InterConn%20IPPBX%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">InterConn</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/Orchard%20Hotel%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">Planet Telecom</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/Global%20Gateway%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">Global Gateway Resource</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/Standard%20Charterd%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">Standard Chartered</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/Allianz%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">Allianz</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/WestPac%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">WesPac</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/Orchard%20Hotel%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">Hewlett Packard</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/Dorsett%20Hotel%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">Dorsett</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onClick="location=document.jump.menu.options[document.jump.menu.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO">
</p>
</form>

<form name="jump">
<p align="left-side" >
<select name="menu">
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/Orchard%20Hotel%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">Orchard Hotel</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/Orchard%20Hotel%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">IDA</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/Park%20Regis%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">Park Regis</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/Golden%20Village%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">Golden Village</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/Orchard%20Hotel%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">NTUC Link</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/MediaCorp%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">MediaCorp</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/South%20Beach%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">South Beach</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/Golden%20Village%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">Golden Village</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/Orchard%20Hotel%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">Gallery</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/InterConn%20IPPBX%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">InterConn</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/Orchard%20Hotel%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">Planet Telecom</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/Global%20Gateway%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">Global Gateway Resource</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/Standard%20Charterd%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">Standard Chartered</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/Allianz%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">Allianz</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/WestPac%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">WesPac</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/Orchard%20Hotel%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">Hewlett Packard</option>
<option value="file:///Z:/OnBoarding%20Docs%20HTML/Dorsett%20Hotel%20OnBoarding%20Docs.htm">Dorsett</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onClick="location=document.jump.menu.options[document.jump.menu.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO">
</p>
</form>
```

Im a newbie in this environment, would like to ask assistance on how am I able to work my simple webpage with multiple dropdown menu list.I know this JS is for single dropdown menu, just want to get some inputs on how to work this in multiple dropdown functions

```js
var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'menu1' );
 urlmenu.onchange = function() {
      window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value );
 };
```

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: can you show your html?

Comment: Tnx folks, but what Im trying to have is to run a multiple dropdown  selection menu with same function

Answer (score 0):

```
very easy
var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'menu1' );
 urlmenu.onchange = function() {
      window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value );
 };
```

is for menu one

```
var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'menu2' );
 urlmenu.onchange = function() {
      window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value );
 };
```

is for menu 2

```
var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'menu3' );
 urlmenu.onchange = function() {
      window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value );
 };
```

is for menu 3

just change the menu1 to anything different

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you actually wanted was to create a common function.

try this:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var myVal = $(this).val();
    alert(myVal);
    //open window code here
    //blah blah
});
```

Check out my [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mmt0knvb/1/)

Comment: Hi Carls Jr, its not working on my end...your understanding on my concern is correct.What I want is 2 dropdown menu list with same function wherein when I did a selection then it will open a new window-page....My JS will work only with 1 dropdown option but when I added another dropdown selection, of course will not work bec of the limitation of the JS I created

Comment: You will need to add jquery so that my code will work.